# The right format for adding multiple pylint plugins to vscode pylint args

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In the [python linting docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_commandline-arguments-and-configuration-files) for VS Code, it has this example for adding plugins to pylint:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django"]
```

I was just wondering what the proper syntax was if I want to add more than one plugin. Should it be:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django", "pylint_flask"]
```

or should it be:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django pylint_flask"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django,pylint_flask"
```

`--load-plugins` takes a comma-separated list of extensions to run.